# Qt Creator разрядность сборки

Tags: makefile, qt, linux

Доброе время суток.

Подскажите, как установить разрядность компиляции проекта в Qt Creator? Имеется:

- 64 разрядный проц,
- поставленная 64 кубунту,
- ну и Qt SDK.

Смысл в том, что проект компилируется под x64, а хотелось бы иметь возможность выбора разрядности сборки. Идеально будет, если подскажите, как это выставлять в самом Qt Creator. Изменить поле параметров сборки я не могу, только добавить новые.

---

Если собирать через qmake, то в `makefile` пишется, что собирается для x64. Но как там исправить, чтобы нормально собралось?

```
CC            = gcc
CXX           = g++
DEFINES       = -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED
CFLAGS        = -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -Isrc/unix -Isrc/qserialdeviceenumerator -Isrc/qserialdevice -I.
LINK          = g++
LFLAGS        = -m64 -Wl,-O1
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS)  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ludev -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7):

Сначала добавляем компилятор требуемой разрядности (если такого нет):

> Tools -> Options -> Build & Run -> Compilers

Добавляем Qt библиотеки необходимой разрядности:

> Tools -> Options -> Build & Run -> Qt Versions

Затем добавляем KIT с данным компилятором и соответстующим набором библиотек

> Tools -> Options -> Build & Run -> Kits

Затем загружаем наш проект. Слева выбираем

> Projects -> Build & Run -> Add Kit

И выбираем только что добавленный Kit.

Дальше вроде бы всё интуитивно понятно должно быть. Тип сборки выбирается внизу слева с помощью кнопки с нарисованным компьютером, над зеленой стрелкой.